# How to apply JSON patch document on the class containing interface type collection

Tags: json, patch, webapi, json-patch

I have following code:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        [JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteConverter<Order>))]
        public List<IOrderContract> Orders { get; set; }      
    }


public class Order : IOrderContract {
        public string OrderName { get; set; }
        public string OrderType { get; set; }
    }



public interface IOrderContract
    {
        string OrderName { get; set; }
        string OrderType { get; set; }
    }
```

When I apply patch using following code:

```
 public IActionResult JsonPatchWithoutModelState([FromBody] JsonPatchDocument<Customer> patchDoc)
        {
            var customer = CreateCustomer();

            patchDoc.ApplyTo(customer);

            return new ObjectResult(customer);
        }



private Customer CreateCustomer()
        {
            return new Customer
            {
                CustomerName = "John",
                Orders = new List<IOrderContract>()
                {
                    new Order
                    {
                        OrderName = "Order0"
                    },
                    new Order
                    {
                        OrderName = "Order1"
                    }
                }
            };
        }
```

It throws exception that 
*

> The value '[   {
>       "OrderName": "name",
>       "OrderType": "type"   } ]' is invalid for target location.

*

But when I use concrete classes collection as following instead of interface:

```
public class Customer
        {
            public string CustomerName { get; set; }    

            public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }      
        }
```

then it works fine. 
I deeply dived into jsonpatchdocument and found that its unable to create instance for interface which is obvious error i.e

> Could not create an instance of type IOrderContract. Type is an interface
>   or abstract class and cannot be instantiated.

**Is there any other solution for this to achieve patch conversion with interfaces?**